# How to successful launch a python cronjob?

Tags: python, linux, cron, sh

In my mind this is an easy task, but i don't know how to realize it.

I have got a python script, that is likely to crash on the first few tries.
(It is calling a websocket, that is not yet ready.)

Can i tell cronjob to keep on trying to run this script until it finally works? Or do i have to implement this in the python script itself?

This is the line in Crontab

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
```

And this is the .sh-file.

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
cd /
sudo python /home/pi/example.py
cd /
```

Comment: implementing it in the Python script (using, for example, `try` and `except`) will almost certainly be more straightforward than implementing it in the shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the task may be specifically, you would probably be best off implementing it in the python script. This seems more straight-forward. For instance:

```
while True:
    try:
        # your task
        # check if it was successful and if so
        break
    except Exception: # a relevant exception would be best
        pass # you could even use sleep() here(time module)
             #  to wait a few seconds between tries
```

Comment: yes this was working. however, i used a modified version, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152564/how-to-retry-just-once-on-exception-in-python). it will try 5 times with 5 seconds in between. that should work. Thank you!